# Binding observable collection to listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a email client for work and I can't get the observable collection to bind to my listview in the correct way. Please, advise as I can't find my exact problem online

C#

```
public partial class Mail : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<GetMails> BindMe = new ObservableCollection<GetMails>();
    public Mail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindMe = FetchAllHeaders(server, port, false, username, password);
        lstMail.ItemsSource = BindMe.ToList();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GetMails> FetchAllHeaders(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username, string password)
    {
        // The client disconnects from the server when being disposed
        using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            GetMails gm = new GetMails();

            // Connect to the server
            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

            // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
            client.Authenticate(username, password);

            // Get the number of messages in the inbox
            int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

            // We want to download all messages
            ObservableCollection<GetMails> getHeaders = new ObservableCollection<GetMails>();

            // Messages are numbered in the interval: [1, messageCount]
            // Ergo: message numbers are 1-based.
            // Most servers give the latest message the highest number
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                MessageHeader headers = client.GetMessageHeaders(i);
                RfcMailAddress from = headers.From;
                Message message = client.GetMessage(i);
                gm.Header = client.GetMessageHeaders(i).Subject;
                gm.From = from.MailAddress.ToString();
                int count = 0;
                foreach (MessagePart attachment in message.FindAllAttachments())
                {
                    count++; 
                }
                gm.NumberAttach = count;
                getHeaders.Add(gm);
            }


            // Now return the fetched messages
            return getHeaders;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="VeriMail.Mail"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded_1" Margin="0,0,-132,0">
    <ListView x:Name="lstMail" Height="399" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,-67,-99" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Subject" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="From" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Number of Attachments"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

The output I get when I do it like this is just VeriMail.GetMail all over

If I change the gridview to this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Header}"/>
<GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="From" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding From}"/>
<GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Number of Attachments" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumberAttach}"/>
```

Then the output changes to the information I want but it copies one email the last one inserted into the observable collection.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: The problem is when you call `ToList` the collection is copied and won't reflect changes in future. Remove that method call and it should work.

However it's better to bind `ItemsSource` in XAML than in code behind:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstMail" ItemsSource="{Binding BindMe, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Height="399" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,-67,-99" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Subject" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="From" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Number of Attachments"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And also not change `BindMe` collection reference itself in `FetchAllHeaders()`, but instead modify it's contents. Otherwise the binding won't work because the reference is again changed.

Comment: Why? What do you think would happen? -1 for providing an incorrect answer.

Comment: @Sheridan Can you explain the reason against binding in XAML?

Comment: There is no reason *not* to set the `ItemSource` in XAML... I *always* do it myself. But there is also no reason *not* to set the `ItemSource` in code behind. So your *You should not assign ItemsSource in code behind* statement is incorrect. Even your edit is still misleading... *it's better to bind `ItemsSource` in XAML than in code behind*. From a technical point of view, the two ways of setting the `ItemsSource` end with identical results, so how can one be better?

Comment: If you say that you prefer to set it in XAML, that's fine. If you said that it better because of this particular reason, that'd be fine too. My point is that your statement that *A is better than B* just isn't true without some sort of context. Of course I'd be happy to remove my down vote if you address your incorrect statement.

Comment: @Sheridan I agree with you that I should not say _you should..._ and thank you for pointing that out. However we don't simply evaluate which is better based on technical result, right? We all have written enough XAML code to know which way leads to better readability and maintainability, especially for this particular problem.

Comment: But that's the problem... that's just according to *your* personal opinion, not necessarily the opinion of the question author, or anyone else who might read your answer. Either way, you've made an effort to address this issue, so I'm happy to remove my down vote now.

Comment: I did try this aswell then it doesnt bind at all how i tested it was i set a message to display on the bindingchange property i have asked 100's of people and they said it is just suppose to work as is

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, its a usual practice to bind in the XAML (e.g. using the MVVM pattern).  If you had done this, you may have found the bug...

```
lstMail.ItemsSource = BindMe.ToList();
```

When you call `ToList()` you create a brand new `List<GetMails>` containing the contents of the observable collection.  When you add a new item, the list doesn't change - it's a copy and knows nothing about the original collection.

Try

```
lstMail.ItemsSource = BindMe;
```

and this should fix your problem.

Comment: *As mentioned in another answer, you should be binding in the XAML*... why??? You don't get down voted because you *did* find the problem, but there is absolutely no problem caused by setting an `ItemsSource` in code... that statement is totally misleading.

Comment: @Sheridan - firstly in this case it would have resolved the issue as it removed the ToList() call.  Secondly - by should I am referring to what is generally accepted as best practice - using MVVM or a similar pattern to provide good separation between components.  However it is not a hard and fast rule, and doing it in code is fine if the situation is appropriate - hence why I said should instead of must.

Comment: @Sheridan He said "you should" _not_ "you have to" and it is, IMHO, better to put the bindings in XAML...

Comment: Tweaked the answer a bit - hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I always declare my `ItemsSource` in XAML, but that doesn't mean that there is anything wrong with setting it in code. I do however accept your point and believe that your edit has improved your answer.

Comment: I will try declaring it in the xaml like showed above

Answer (score 0):

```
lstMail.ItemsSource = BindMe.ToList();
```

should be

```
lstMail.ItemsSource = BindMe;
```

Binding to a list is different than binding to an ObservableCollection.
Observable collection is the object to use for binding because it implements ICollectionChanged. List does not.